# run a batch with parameters from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file with arguments, it should be dynamic but it does not work the way the I want it to.

I have some code with a specific directory that works, I want to make it more dynamic. I'm retrieving a directory from a textBox in visual studio.

```
String rep_source = textBox12.Text;
String attribute = textBox4.Text;
String rep_destination = textBox5.Text;
String poly_dest = textBox13.Text;
string SPECIFIC_DIRECTORY= textBox7.Text; //I want to use this for my code
string command = @"/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\Folder1\Folder2\batchfile.Bat" + " " + rep_source + " " + poly_dest + " " + attribute + " " + rep_destination;
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", command);
```

thing code works but when I'm trying to the retrieved directory.

```
 string command = @"/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted " +SPECIFIC_DIRECTORY +"\\batchfile.Bat" + " " + rep_source + " " + poly_dest + " " + attribute + " " + rep_destination;
```

This would not compile and give me what I want.
i'm not even able to reach the batchfile itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```cs
String com = @"/c powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\Folder1\Folder2\batchfile.Bat" + " " + rep_source + " " + poly_dest + " " + attribute + " " + rep_destination;
ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + com );
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

Comment: There's no reason to start `cmd` when the shell you want is *powershell*.